# Mediaconvert Network failure

Tags: amazon-web-services

My AWS Elemental Media Convert is showing:

> **undefined (undefined)**
> Network Failure: {"message":"Network Failure","code":"NetworkingError","time":"xxx","hostname":"mediaconvert-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com","retryable":true}

Answer (score 0):

The undefined network failure error is a sort of catch-all, so a closer look at the job configuration and access permissions to any specified resources (S3 buckets, IAM roles, etc.) would be required to identify the exact cause.  I would recommend opening a ticket with AWS support for additional support.

When I've seen this error, the most common reason was because the user was specifying a MediaConvert queue that belonged to a different AWS account.  Check to make sure you aren't referencing any resources that your account/role don't have access to, and make sure you're running the job in the correct region (if any referenced resources are region-specific).

A future update to MediaConvert will address this generalized error to make it more specific and actionable by the user.

Comment: Thanks buddy I will check and get back to you